# jquery find() checkbox with a certain value

Tags: jquery, find

I have a list of checkboxes like so below wrapped in a div.

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="checkbox"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="checkbox"/>
</div>
<select class="value">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Using jquery, i would like on change for the select option, the checkbox with the value 1 to be checked.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems? Selecting the checkbox or making the selection when the value of the select control changes?

Comment: Please, before posting a question, read carefully the [FAQ][http://stackoverflow.com/faq]. Your question is a common jQuery issue . The solution can be found with a minimal effort just having a look in the jQuery api, or searching similar question in Stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699237/uncheck-checkbox-when-certain-values-from-drop-down-is-choosen).

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
$(".value").change(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox][value=1]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but OP wants to check checkbox with value 1 on **any** change in select list? At least it's what I've understood...

Answer (score 2):

```
// Call the select list on change event 
$(".value").change(function() {

    // Reset all the check-boxes ckecked
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);

    // Set the chekbox with the same value as select option
    $('input:checkbox[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wadwA/)

Comment: How would look like the answer/find-expression with complex values, like `value="Smith, David"`?

Comment: @TheBndr `Smith, David` are values of single checkbox element?

Comment: yes. The value looks like that: `<input type="checkbox" value="Smith, David"> `

Comment: @TheBndr Then try `$('input:checkbox[value="Smith, David"]').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try  something like

```
$(".value").change(function() {
   $(":checkbox[value="+this.value+"]").prop('checked',true)    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if($("Select.value").val()==1){

$("input[type='checkbox'][value=1]").attr('checked','checked');

}
```

Comment: So, you would have an `if` statement for every possible value of the select control? That does not seem to be a very good solution.